# I am trying to make a custom flask decorator for a multi login system

Tags: flask, decorator, python-decorators

I and making a flask app for appointments. I made a admin page and sudo admin page for different levels of login and different levels of authorities. For the admin section and page access after login I used @login_required decorator:

```
@views.route('/admin-page-contact-list')
@login_required
def admin_page_contact_list():
    contact_enter = ContactForm.query.all()
    return render_template("admin-page-contact-ent.html", contact_form = contact_enter)
```

the above is the sample of the admin page where the admin can see all the contact form entries.

I wanted to do the same for my sudo admin access because i dont want others to access the sudo admin page and create new admins and gain access.

Initially i tried and used the same @login_required decorator which i realized is wrong because i have used it already for one level of access. After some research i found out that we can create a custom decorator. so i created a decorator

```
def sudo_admin_login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        if not current_user.is_authenticated or not current_user.is_sudo_admin:
            flash('Please contact store authorities for any extra Info!', category='error')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_view
```

I made this decorator and used it where ever i wanted to give access only to sudo admin for example

```
@views.route('/sudo-admin-page-contact-list')
@sudo_admin_login_required
def sudo_admin_page_contact_list():
    return render_template('sudo-admin-page-contact-ent.html')
```

this shows all the contact entries to the sudo admin.

```
auth.route('/sudo-admin-login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sudo_admin_login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sudoAdminEmail = request.form.get('sudo-admin-email')
        sudoAdminIdNumber = request.form.get('sudo-admin-id-key')
        sudoAdminPassword = request.form.get('sudo-admin-password')

        sudo_admin = SudoAdminAccount.query.filter_by(sudoAdminEmail = sudoAdminEmail).first()
        if sudo_admin:
            if check_password_hash(sudo_admin.sudoAdminIdKey, sudoAdminIdNumber):
                if check_password_hash(sudo_admin.sudoAdminPassword, sudoAdminPassword):
                    flash('Logged In successfully!', category='success')
                    return redirect(url_for('views.sudo_admin_page_contact_list'))
                else:
                    flash('Incorrect Password, Try again!', category='error')
            else:
                flash('Incorrect Sudo Admin ID, Try again!', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email Doesnot Exist!', category='error')

    return render_template("sudo-admin-login.html")
```

the above code is my sudo admin login code.

as soon as i login with the email sudo admin id key and password i get flashed that the login was succcessfull and there is one more flashed msg that says 'Please contact store authorities for any extra Info!' and I get redirected to views.home page but i want it such that if the login is unsuccessful that the user gets redirect to views.home but if it is successful the the sudo admin gets redirected to views.sudo_admin_page_contact_list